Python typing game - Countdown timer that exits program after given time
I am trying to build a rough typing game for a school project. I tried using the threading method(which I only know a tiny bit of) to make the timer run simultaneously with input. The idea is to stop the typing game once the timer is up. Maybe there can be an alternative solution that does not involve the use of threading which can allow typing and counting down at the same time.
What I ended up with my method was I could only stop the typing when I hit return and the time up stop was not working. Thank you for your help!
My code:
import time
import datetime
import random
import threading
library = ["Hello","World"] 
#There will be some text here

alphabet = {'a':0,'A':0,'b':0,'B':0,'c':0,'C':0,'d':0,'D':0,'e':0,'E':0,'f':0,'F':0,'g':0,'G':0,'h':0,'H':0,'i':0,'I':0,'J':0,'j':0,'k':0,'K':0,'l':0,'L':0,'m':0,'M':0,'n':0,'N':0,'o':0,'O':0,'p':0,'P':0,'q':0,'Q':0,'r':0,'R':0,'s':0,'S':0,'t':0,'T':0,'u':0,'U':0,'v':0,'V':0,'w':0,'W':0,'x':0,'X':0,'y':0,'Y':0,'z':0,'Z':0,',':0,'.':0,'-':0,"'":0,":":0}
alphabet2 = {'a':0,'A':0,'b':0,'B':0,'c':0,'C':0,'d':0,'D':0,'e':0,'E':0,'f':0,'F':0,'g':0,'G':0,'h':0,'H':0,'i':0,'I':0,'J':0,'j':0,'k':0,'K':0,'l':0,'L':0,'m':0,'M':0,'n':0,'N':0,'o':0,'O':0,'p':0,'P':0,'q':0,'Q':0,'r':0,'R':0,'s':0,'S':0,'t':0,'T':0,'u':0,'U':0,'v':0,'V':0,'w':0,'W':0,'x':0,'X':0,'y':0,'Y':0,'z':0,'Z':0,',':0,'.':0,'-':0,"'":0,"!":0,":":0}
def countdown1(h, m, s):

  total_seconds = h * 3600 + m * 60 + s

  while total_seconds > 0:

      # Timer represents time left on countdown
      timer = datetime.timedelta(seconds = total_seconds)

      print(timer, end="\r")
      # Delays the program one second
      time.sleep(1)

      # Reduces total time by one second
      total_seconds -= 1
  print("Start now!")

done = False
def countdown2():
  c = 0
  if done:
    print("You used "+str(c)+" seconds to type!! Good Job!!")
  while not done:
    time.sleep(1)
    c += 1
  
  
count = 0
print('You have 1 minute to type the following text')
c = random.randint(0,len(library)-1)
print(library[c])
print('Type after countdown, hit return after finishing or when the time is up')
countdown1(0,0,3)
threading.Thread(target=countdown2,daemon = True).start()
word = input().replace(" ", "")
done = True
passage = library[c].replace(" ", "")
total = len(passage)
for i in passage:
  if i in alphabet2:
    alphabet2[i] += 1
letter1 = []
letter2 = []
for i in word:
  if i in alphabet:
    alphabet[i] += 1
for key in alphabet.values():
  letter1.append(int(key))
for key in alphabet2.values():
  letter2.append(int(key))
for j in range(57):
  count += min(letter1[j],letter2[j])
print('Congrats! You got '+str(count)+'/'+str(total)+' right!')


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

https://github.dev/Suki0524/q4/blob/main/main.py – requires authorization. Please post your code in question.

@Alderven Sorry this is my first time using it. I posted my code in the question. Thank you!

I don't know is it acceptable for you but you can create such typing game with Tkinter without using threading lib:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

window = tk.Tk()
timeout = 30
time_left = timeout
label = tk.Label(window, text=time_left)
label.config(font=('Courier', 44))
label.pack()
text = tk.Text(window)
text.pack()


def update():
    global time_left
    global text
    time_left -= 1
    label.configure(text=time_left)
    if time_left > 0:
        window.after(1000, update)
    else:
        tk.messagebox.showinfo('Your score', str(len(text.get('1.0', 'end-1c'))))


window.after(1000, update)
window.mainloop()


